# What is CLI execute error in SAS?

Tags: sas, teradata

I am trying to use SAS to upload a table into teradata. The table started to upload, the names of the variable got uploaded and the table was created. However I got

`ERROR: CLI execute error: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Character string truncated`

What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI execute error is an often-not-very-helpful error message SAS returns when it receives an error from the RDBMS when it submits code; in this case it may not be a true error, it may simply be saying that one or more of your character strings didn't fit in the columns.